# R - Instagram hashtag scraping

Tags: r, json, instagram

I am trying to acess information about post's hashtags and those related to them. I am attempting to transform the json into R - using the following

```
library(jsonlite)

hashtag <- "sponsored"
url_start <- str_glue("http://instagram.com/explore/tags/{hashtag}/?__a=1")
json <- fromJSON(url_start)
```

I get this error

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"
                     (right here) ------^
```

I can get something out if I use a single user, e.g. my own username instead of the {hashtag}. Looking into the #'s i just cant get it to work. I currently think this an Instagram problem with them blocking the request?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you run `httr::GET(url_start)` you'll see that you're being blocked at a login attempt.

Instagram has put your IP on a block-list.

Don't spam, just do something else and wait for 2-3 days, and hopefully the block would be repealed.

Once the code starts working again, make sure to add
`Sys.sleep(sample(4:20,1))` before you run
`json <- fromJSON(url_start)`